# Contains in a where condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements, where-clause, contains

Tech specs: ruby 2.2.1p85, Rails 4.2.3.

This is working perfectly:

```
@performances = Performance.where(date: start_date..end_date).includes(:production_page).where(pages: {organization_id: organization_id, layout_id: nil, genre: genre_word})
```

My issue is that currently, genre and genre_word need to be an exact match. I need to know if genre contains genre_word. I've tried include? (syntax error) and tried to rewrite the query using .find_by_sql.

Example:

```
genre_word: Comedy

pages.genre: Comedy, Drama
```

Ideally, pages.genre and genre_word would see this record as a match since "Comedy" in in pages.genre. I have to maintain the search on organization_id and the layout_id as well.

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: I think you have this reversed: `genre_word: genre` should be: `genre: genre_word`. Then it should at least match if a page has only the `genre_word` set as the `genre`. Is that correct?

Comment: You are right. Editing above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution ended up being:

```
@performances = Performance.includes(:production_page)
   .where("pages.genre LIKE ?", "%#{genre}%").references(:production_page)
```

Thanks to anyone who helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL `LIKE` or `ILIKE` operators to do partial string matching. A simple example:

```
genre_name = "Drama"
Article.where("genre LIKE ?", "%#{genre_name}%")
```

This will generate the SQL query:

```
SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE (name LIKE '%Drama%')
```

`ILIKE` is the case-insensitive sister of `LIKE`. The percent sign will match zero or more characters before or after the search term, so in the case of the example, it will also match if an Article has genre 'Comedy, Drama'.

Comment: I really appreciate the answer but the key part is that I need to maintain the other variables as well.                                                         @performances = Performance.where(date: start_date..end_date).includes(:production_pagestatus_id: 100, display_on_district_calendar: 1, organization_id: organization_id, layout_id: nil, "genre LIKE ?", "%#{genre_word}%"}) leads to a syntax error (syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
...layout_id: nil, "genre LIKE ?").

Comment: I see. What if you add another `where` for the `LIKE` part? `@performances = Performance.where(date: start_date..end_date).includes(:production_page).where(pages: {organization_id: organization_id, layout_id: nil}).where(pages: { "genre LIKE ?", "%#{genre_word}%" })`